# jQuery Color Cycle on a href links (Maximum call stack size exceeded and Firefox Issues.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, colors

I'm attempting to make a page that will animate the `a href` links through a table of colors nice and smoothly. I currently have 2 problems with the code that I'm using experiencing a whole mix of problems relating to bad code (please note that JavaScript and jQuery I'm pretty damn weak at). I'm hoping that some Guru can spend 2mins and let me know what the problem or supply a better solution. (thanks in advance.).

*Problems Encountered:*

1. `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`
2. `Firefox is not smooth  while Chrome is (Firefox just changes color).`
3. `Some hues are too dark`
4. `Performance seems an issue, maybe this is because of the Maximum stack size error`

*Libraries:*

1. jQuery.v1.10.2.min.js
2. jQuery.color-2.1.0.js

*Code:*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    spectrum(); 
    function spectrum(){
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
        jQuery('body a').animate( { color: hue }, 2000);
    spectrum(); 
    }   
});
```

*What I need:*

Basically all I need is a script that will animate all links on the page from one color to another every 2seconds or more... smoothly. Ideally, I'll like to be able to select 6 or more colors that I know that work but due to my limited knowledge in JavaScript I don't know where to begin.

**JSFiddle of the Code in Action**

I've made a jsfiddle to hopefully save anyone time or just check what the current output looks like: **http://jsfiddle.net/ebZ3x/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you're recursively calling indefinitely which will quickly run you out of stack space. What you want instead is for the browser to regularly call your color changing function. We'll use window.setInterval() to accomplish that.

Then we'll also create an array of the six colors you want and we'll just randomly index into it. To add more colors just add them to the array.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    function spectrum(){
        var colors = [
            'rgb(256,0,0)', //red
            'rgb(0,256,0)', //green
            'rgb(0,0,256)', //blue
            'rgb(256,256,0)', //orange
            'rgb(256,0,256)', //magenta
            'rgb(0,256,256)']; //cyan        
        var hue = colors[(Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length))];

        jQuery('body a').animate( { color: hue }, 2000);
    }

    var intervalId = window.setInterval(spectrum, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on your question since you posted it yesterday, and I thought I would give it a shot so I might learn a little about setTimeout. And boy, have I learned - about the complexity of such a "simple" command. It's probably the most difficult I've encountered in javascript.

So I present my "answer" just as something to be viewed, with JoeClacks' answer obviously superior.

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/p3Yh6/1/) shows the initiation of the timer (runmytimer) after loading the DOM. It changes the background color of two divs randomly. I've let it run for over an hour and it seems not to crash.

I added the "extra" stuff to make sure other things on the page don't interfere with the timer. So when you type into an input box, the timer continues. When you click the "save" button (I just moved the input text to another div) the timer continues.

Here is the relevant JS

```
var randomcolors = ['#FF00FF','#00FFFF','#FFFF00','#0000FF','#00FF00','#FF0000','#000000','#C0C0C0','#C0C1C1','#CFCHCH','#CCFFCC'];

var timer;
//var timer_is_on = 0;
runmytimer();

$('#saveme').click(function(){
        var moveme = $('#getme').val();
        $('.movemehere').html(moveme);
});

function runmytimer()
{
  t = setTimeout( function(){ runmytimer() }, 1000 );
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
     $('.putmehere1').css('background-color', randomcolors[random]);
     $('.putmehere2').css('background-color', randomcolors[random+1]);
}
```

For other noobs such as myself who are reading this, I've learned a few things that aren't clearly stated in any  documentation (I went to 30-40 sites, that weren't really that helpful).

1. If you try to put a timer in a loop - its behavior is NOT intuitive. I'm used to BASIC loops where when you do something to STOP the loop - oddly - it STOPS! :-). Not so with javascript. As an experiment I did a loop with a setTimeout in it, and put the i's of the loop in a div. What chaos! The loop printed out all the i's before the first setTimeout was done! I read that the loop is actually creating a different timer for each loop of the setTimeout. Disaster!
2. You can stop a timer with clearTimeout(nameoftimer).
3. I'm guessing if you have a routine that stops a timer, it could be restarted at the bottom of the routine with setTimeout(nameoftimer).
4. I still haven't figured out why a variable assignment such as var timer = setTimeout ( alert('hello'), 1000 ); would not only assign the variable to the code, but also run the code. Not intuitive.
5. After going to all the sites and trying their code, I went to W3Schools (not held in high esteem by many) and found code that actually worked! I derived my fiddle from that.

Anyway, thanks for the question. I learned a lot!